# Integration By Substitution in indefinite Integrals

Tags: calculus

In integration By Substitution we substitute $u=g(x)$ and with the condition that $g(x)$ is a continuously differentiable function but while solving the integral $$\int x \sqrt{x-5}\, dx$$ we substitute $\sqrt{x-5}=t$ but $\sqrt{x-5}$ is not differentiable at $x=5$

Comment: There is a problem in your question since $x \sqrt{x-5}$ is not defined when $x < 5$.

Comment: O sorry I wanted to say that $\sqrt{x-5}$ is not differentiable at $x=5$

Answer (score 2):

Instead, try the substitution $u=x-5$. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Since the domain of this function $f(x)=\sqrt{x-5}$ where it is real, finite and unique is $[5,\infty)$. You do not have to bother about $x=0$, you will be aked in find its definite integral only in a subset of $[5,\infty).$
Check that the integral $$\int_{5}^{9} x \sqrt{x-5} ~dx$$ does not pose any problem because this integral means $\int_{5^+}^{9^-} x \sqrt{x-5} dx.$

$$\int_{5}^{9} x \sqrt{x-5} dx= [x \frac{2}{3} (x-5)^{3/2}-\frac{4}{15} (x-5)^{5/2}]_{5}^{9}=\frac{592}{15}$$

Comment: No the function is not differentiable at $x=5$

Comment: See my edited answer.